# Add magnificPopup to dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I worked with below code it will pop up the content I want

```
function init_magnificPopup()
{
    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({

        type: 'inline',

        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,

        overflowY: 'auto',

        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,

        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    init_magnificPopup();
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-primary popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#dialog">dialog popup</a> 

<div id="dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
popup content
</div>
```

Now how can I work with below dynamically created tag with class `.popup-with-zoom-anim`?

```
var content_string +=  '<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#dialog">dynamic dialog popup</a>';
$( "body" ).html(content_string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the [answer](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/778) which using `.on()` method and chaining **`.magnificPopup('open');`** to the end

```
$("body").on('click', '.popup-with-zoom-anim', function(){ 

     $(this).magnificPopup({

                type: 'inline',

                fixedContentPos: false,
                fixedBgPos: true,

                overflowY: 'auto',

                closeBtnInside: true,
                preloader: false,

                midClick: true,
                removalDelay: 300,
                mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
            }).magnificPopup('open');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`delegate` option](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#initializing-popup):

```js
$('body').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a.popup-with-zoom-anim',
    type: 'inline',
    ...
});
```